# convert byte array to png file python

Tags: python

I send compressed png file with android studio to python server
and I try to convert the compressed byte array back to PNG image file using PIl
but I get black image
how to convert the compressed PNG file back to image using python

this is my python code

```
while True:

    data = sock.recv(100000)

    if str(data) == "b''":
        continue

    print(data)

    image1 = io.BytesIO(data)

    image = Image.open(image1).convert("RGBA")
    image.show()
```

and this is my java code that compressed the image

```
class sendImg implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,80,bout);
            long len = bout.size();
            out.write(bout.toByteArray());

            socket.close();

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(e.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could change the python code to save the raw bytes into a file and confirm that you're getting a legit PNG file first?

Comment: i did it and its still a black image

Comment: if you send PNG then you should get PNG without any conversion.  First you could write it in file `fh = open(..., 'wb')` `fh.write(data)`, `fh.close()` and open in any image viewer.

Comment: BTW: instead `if str(data) == "b''":` you can do `if data == b'':` eventually `if not data:`

Comment: what do you get with `print(data)` ? `recv()` doesn't have to get all data at once. Maybe it gets only part of data and you have to wait for rest of data before you try to display it. And this is good to send first size of image and then receiver will know how many data need to get. And this is called "protocol".